# Type of glue for sealing cable entries

Tags: electrical, waterproofing, outdoor, adhesive

I am looking for the name of a type of glue (I think brand recommendations are not permitted, so not that) which will seal an electrical connector to the socket it is plugged into in a **reversible** and **temporary** manner. I've scraped this stuff off before and it is usually some form of yellowish translucent gum. The exact use case is sealing a USB plug to a waterproof USB solar-powered power pack (and the other end of the cable to the similarly waterproof thing I'm plugging it into), so this can be used outdoors.

Comment: Silicone caulking?

Comment: I’ve heard the brand name Silastic (DuPont, I think ) used for this type of non-conductive glue.

Answer (score 3):

Not what you are describing, but "duct seal" is a (all I've ever seen is gray) non-hardening putty intended for plugging conduits to prevent various things (air, water, rodents, insects) from coming along with the wires, usually at building penetration points. Find it where electrical supplies are sold, though it may not be all that obvious on the shelf.

It is removable and reusable.

What you are describing sounds more like hot glue (which could work, though its performance exposed to sunlight may be dubious.)